# Drawing adjacent texture mapped rectangles in OpenGL

Tags: opengl, textures, texture-mapping

I'm drawing a number of texture-mapped rectangles which are sat on top of each other using the following code:

```
glBegin(GL_QUADS);
glTexCoord2f(0.0, 1.0); glVertex3f(x, y, 0);
glTexCoord2f(0.0, 0.0); glVertex3f(x, y + dy, 0);
glTexCoord2f(1.0, 0.0); glVertex3f(x + dx, y + dy, 0);
glTexCoord2f(1.0, 1.0); glVertex3f(x + dx, y, 0);
glEnd();
```

This renders correctly at full size, but when I resize it with `glScale`, single-pixel gaps appear in between some of the rectangles.

However, if I remove the texture map, the rectangles always abut each other correctly.

What's going wrong, and how can I fix this?

Comment: seems correct. can you post the code where you are scaling?

Comment: @0verbose I didn't bother posting it because it's pretty simple. I'm just calling this before the code above: `glScale(scalex, scaley, 1);` (scalex and scaley are both GLfloats with values < 1).

Comment: How are x, y, dx and dy computed ?

Comment: @Bahbar x, dx and dy are constant. y is set to an inital value and then after each call to the code above there's a line: `y -= dy`.

Comment: AS @Paul-Jan said, how do you know for sure it's gaps as opposed to texture artifacts ? Can you share a pic ?

Comment: @Bahbar It's actually rendering correctly! The absence of gaps was actually the artifact. See my answer below. Thanks for all the answers. Apologies for wasting everyone's time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm an idiot. The images I was using actually had a transparent row of pixels along the top and bottom.

The original "full-size" rendering was already resizing the texture, and it was a pure fluke that resizing artifacts caused the transparent rows not to be displayed in this case.

Then when I resized the whole lot again with glScale some of the artifacts must have disappeared, and the transparent pixels appeared as gaps.

Answer (score 1):

How does the texture look like? Maybe you've to use a different clamping mode, depending on the texture's contents.

Comment: They're essentially just plain white rectangles, with a little shading around the edges to give them depth. I'm using `GL_CLAMP_TO_EDGE`, but changing this doesn't seem to have any effect.

Answer (score 1):

First of all, make sure they are really *gaps*, and not texture artifacts, by not using any alpha channel (assuming you were) and picking a background color that stands out like a sore thumb.

Even though you pinpointed texturing as the root cause, a much more likely culprit is rounding errors in the vertex coordinates. Rasterization of adjacent triangles is only guaranteed to be gap-free if the vertex coordinates used match 100%. In stead of calculating them on the fly (x + dx, y + dy), why not store them in an array and make sure you re-use the same coordinates?

Comment: I initially thought rounding error was the likely culprit, but if that's the case, I don't understand how commenting out the `glTexCoord2f` calls can cause the gaps to disappear.